# MVC Razor View Ajax Call Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an Ajax Request within my MVC 5 Razor View which is supposed to call an Action within my Controller, which in turn should return Json Data back to my Razor View.

**Razor View**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            //url: '@Url.Action("GetTestData")',
            url: '/Statistics/GetTestData',
            error: function () {
                alert("An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);
            }
        });

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);

});
```

**MVC Controller**

```
namespace STAR.UI.Controllers
{
    public class StatisticsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetTestData()
        {
            return Json(new[] { new[] { 0, 5 }, new[] { 1, 10 }, new[] { 2, 15 }, new[] { 3, 20 }, new[] { 4, 25 }, new[] { 5, 30 }, new[] { 6, 35 } },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

The Ajax Request should call the GetTestData Action in my Controller and return the Json data. However, I've put a break point on my GetTestData Action, debugged, and the Action never gets called, therefore the Json data is never returned.

Could anyone please help me find out why my Action isn't called by my Ajax code.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: have you consider this line: url: '/Statistics/GetTestData")'? it should be url: '/Statistics/GetTestData'

Comment: try specifyig `content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @SoftSan Apologies, that was a typo in my question. I've now corrected, but still the Action does not get called?

Comment: Is the name of the controller `StatisticsController`?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Thanks, I tried that, but it still doesn't get called. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SimonLinder Yes Simon, it is.

Comment: specify `dataType` and `content-type` both

Comment: Does putting that URL in your browser work?

Comment: @DavidG Nice idea David. Yes, when I put the URL into my browser (http://localhost:54733/Statistics/GetTestData) it does hit my break point on that Action.

Comment: @tgriffiths Good sign! Now I'd check if your jQuery is actually calling anything. Do your browser dev tools show anything being called?

Comment: Some other (likely unrelated) comments. 1. You don't need to specify `contentType` as you are not POSTing anything, though you may need `dataType` for the response type. 2. Try not to mix single and double quotes in your jQuery, it can be confusing.

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your help. There seems to be a problem with my JQuery file because when I put an alert in the document.ready it isn't being called. I'm going to replace my JQuery file and see if that helps. Thanks again for all your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Does this code appear AFTER the jQuery definition?

Comment: @DavidG Yes it does. Just checked the console errors and found this one - http://localhost:54733/Scripts/jquery.min.map - 404 (Not Found) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are having typo here :-

do

```
url: '/Statistics/GetTestData',
```

instead of :-

```
  url: '/Statistics/GetTestData")',
```

plus you need to specify datatype as below :-

```
dataType: 'json'
```

and content type as below :-

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo in my question. I've now corrected, but still the Action does not get called?

Comment: are you sure you have given ref of jquery to the file @tgriffiths

Comment: first make sure that ur ajax call is executing or not @tgriffiths

Comment: Yes, I have this referenced in the <head></head> tag <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: put alert in document.ready and check if it is hitting the script or no on page load @tgriffiths